# How to applied finite difference into partial equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

I am trying to use finite difference method to numerically solve a pair of partial differential equation by using Matlab. 
 [image: Main equation and boundary condition]

So far, this is my working .
[image: Working for 1st equation]

[image: Working for 2nd equation]

Did my working calculation on finite differences correct?
For matlab coding (don't known anything) i still learn the basic thing on how to create the coding from youtube.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset maths.

Comment: @Harry49 sorry i dont know how to use it. my bad.